# DreamWeavers sees lots of errors, while script does work with jQuery3

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error, warnings

Dreamweaver colors many lines red with warning. The script works perfectly with jQuery 3! So are these DreamWeaver warnings to be neglected or should (some of these) be changed, and if so how?  I have manually written them down since the can only be seen when hovering the mouse over the line numbers.

- Missing semicolon (line 2)
- Use strict statement (line 4)
- Expected === but saw == (line 10)
- Expected !==but saw != (line 23)
- Expected and assignment or call but saw expression (line 33)
- Missing semicolon (41)
- Expected === but saw == (43)
- Missing use strict statement (45)
- the body of a for in statement should be wrapped in an if statement to filter unwanted properties from the prototype (46)
- Expected { but saw e (52)
- Expected === but saw == (53)
- Expecte { but saw for (54)
- Expected { but saw e (55)
- Expected === but saw == (60)
- Expected and assignment or call but saw expression (70)
- Expected and assignment or call but saw expression (75)
- Missing semicolon (77)
- Expected === but saw == (84)
- Expected and assignment or call but saw expression (92)
- Expected { but saw for (101)
- Expected and assignment or call but saw expression (103)

---

```
 ! function(t, e) {
    "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define("ev-emitter/ev-emitter", e) : "object" == typeof module && module.exports ? module.exports = e() : t.EvEmitter = e()
}(this, function() {
    function t() {}
    var e = t.prototype;
    return e.on = function(t, e) {
        if (t && e) {
            var i = this._events = this._events || {},
                n = i[t] = i[t] || [];
            return -1 == n.indexOf(e) && n.push(e), this
        }
    }, e.once = function(t, e) {
        if (t && e) {
            this.on(t, e);
            var i = this._onceEvents = this._onceEvents || {},
                n = i[t] = i[t] || [];
            return n[e] = !0, this;
        }
    }, e.off = function(t, e) {
        var i = this._events && this._events[t];
        if (i && i.length) {
            var n = i.indexOf(e);
            return -1 != n && i.splice(n, 1), this
        }
    }, e.emitEvent = function(t, e) {
        var i = this._events && this._events[t];
        if (i && i.length) {
            var n = 0,
                o = i[n];
            e = e || [];
            for (var r = this._onceEvents && this._onceEvents[t]; o;) {
                var s = r && r[o];
                s && (this.off(t, o), delete r[o]), o.apply(this, e), n += s ? 0 : 1, o = i[n]
            }
            return this;
        }
    }, t;
}),
function(t, e) {
    "use strict";
    "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define(["ev-emitter/ev-emitter"], function(i) {
        return e(t, i);
    }) : "object" == typeof module && module.exports ? module.exports = e(t, require("ev-emitter")) : t.imagesLoaded = e(t, t.EvEmitter)
}(window, function(t, e) {
    function i(t, e) {
        for (var i in e) t[i] = e[i];
        return t;
    }

    function n(t) {
        var e = [];
        if (Array.isArray(t)) e = t;
        else if ("number" == typeof t.length)
            for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) e.push(t[i]);
        else e.push(t);
        return e;
    }

    function o(t, e, r) {
        return this instanceof o ? ("string" == typeof t && (t = document.querySelectorAll(t)), this.elements = n(t), this.options = i({}, this.options), "function" == typeof e ? r = e : i(this.options, e), r && this.on("always", r), this.getImages(), h && (this.jqDeferred = new h.Deferred), void setTimeout(function() {
            this.check();
        }.bind(this))) : new o(t, e, r);
    }

    function r(t) {
        this.img = t;
    }

    function s(t, e) {
        this.url = t, this.element = e, this.img = new Image();
    }
    var h = t.jQuery,
        a = t.console;
    o.prototype = Object.create(e.prototype), o.prototype.options = {}, o.prototype.getImages = function() {
        this.images = [], this.elements.forEach(this.addElementImages, this)
    }, o.prototype.addElementImages = function(t) {
        "IMG" == t.nodeName && this.addImage(t); this.options.background === !0 && this.addElementBackgroundImages(t);
        var e = t.nodeType;
        if (e && d[e]) {
            for (var i = t.querySelectorAll("img"), n = 0; n < i.length; n++) {
                var o = i[n];
                this.addImage(o);
            }
            if ("string" == typeof this.options.background) {
                var r = t.querySelectorAll(this.options.background);
                for (n = 0; n < r.length; n++) {
                    var s = r[n];
                    this.addElementBackgroundImages(s);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    var d = {
        1: !0,
        9: !0,
        11: !0
    };
    return o.prototype.addElementBackgroundImages = function(t) {
        var e = getComputedStyle(t);
        if (e)
            for (var i = /url\((['"])?(.*?)\1\)/gi, n = i.exec(e.backgroundImage); null !== n;) {
                var o = n && n[2];
                o && this.addBackground(o, t), n = i.exec(e.backgroundImage)
            }
    }, o.prototype.addImage = function(t) {
        var e = new r(t);
        this.images.push(e)
    }, o.prototype.addBackground = function(t, e) {
        var i = new s(t, e);
        this.images.push(i)
    }, o.prototype.check = function() {
        function t(t, i, n) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                e.progress(t, i, n)
            })
        }
        var e = this;
        return this.progressedCount = 0, this.hasAnyBroken = !1, this.images.length ? void this.images.forEach(function(e) {
            e.once("progress", t), e.check()
        }) : void this.complete()
    }, o.prototype.progress = function(t, e, i) {
        this.progressedCount++, this.hasAnyBroken = this.hasAnyBroken || !t.isLoaded, this.emitEvent("progress", [this, t, e]), this.jqDeferred && this.jqDeferred.notify && this.jqDeferred.notify(this, t), this.progressedCount == this.images.length && this.complete(), this.options.debug && a && a.log("progress: " + i, t, e)
    }, o.prototype.complete = function() {
        var t = this.hasAnyBroken ? "fail" : "done";
        if (this.isComplete = !0, this.emitEvent(t, [this]), this.emitEvent("always", [this]), this.jqDeferred) {
            var e = this.hasAnyBroken ? "reject" : "resolve";
            this.jqDeferred[e](this)
        }
    }, r.prototype = Object.create(e.prototype), r.prototype.check = function() {
        var t = this.getIsImageComplete();
        return t ? void this.confirm(0 !== this.img.naturalWidth, "naturalWidth") : (this.proxyImage = new Image, this.proxyImage.addEventListener("load", this), this.proxyImage.addEventListener("error", this), this.img.addEventListener("load", this), this.img.addEventListener("error", this), void(this.proxyImage.src = this.img.src))
    }, r.prototype.getIsImageComplete = function() {
        return this.img.complete && void 0 !== this.img.naturalWidth
    }, r.prototype.confirm = function(t, e) {
        this.isLoaded = t, this.emitEvent("progress", [this, this.img, e])
    }, r.prototype.handleEvent = function(t) {
        var e = "on" + t.type;
        this[e] && this[e](t)
    }, r.prototype.onload = function() {
        this.confirm(!0, "onload"), this.unbindEvents()
    }, r.prototype.onerror = function() {
        this.confirm(!1, "onerror"), this.unbindEvents()
    }, r.prototype.unbindEvents = function() {
        this.proxyImage.removeEventListener("load", this), this.proxyImage.removeEventListener("error", this), this.img.removeEventListener("load", this), this.img.removeEventListener("error", this)
    }, s.prototype = Object.create(r.prototype), s.prototype.check = function() {
        this.img.addEventListener("load", this), this.img.addEventListener("error", this), this.img.src = this.url;
        var t = this.getIsImageComplete();
        t && (this.confirm(0 !== this.img.naturalWidth, "naturalWidth"), this.unbindEvents())
    }, s.prototype.unbindEvents = function() {
        this.img.removeEventListener("load", this), this.img.removeEventListener("error", this)
    }, s.prototype.confirm = function(t, e) {
        this.isLoaded = t, this.emitEvent("progress", [this, this.element, e])
    }, o.makeJQueryPlugin = function(e) {
        e = e || t.jQuery, e && (h = e, h.fn.imagesLoaded = function(t, e) {
            var i = new o(this, t, e);
            return i.jqDeferred.promise(h(this))
        })
    }, o.makeJQueryPlugin(), o
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stylistic warnings in minified third party libraries can safely be ignored.

Minifiers will almost always trim semicolons when they can, while linters will always warn about semicolons missing.